# No results from foreach loops

Tags: r, dataframe

Below is code to identify duplicates using fuzzy matching.  The original for loops are commented out and replaced with foreach loops.  It doesn't produce any output error messages.

```
library(foreach)
library(parallel)
library(doParallel)

cl <- makeCluster(2)
registerDoParallel(cl)

sample_data <- structure(list(idnty_frst_nm = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("I","Ima", "L"), class = "factor"), idnty_last_nm = structure(c(1L,1L, 2L), .Label = c("NINJA", "starr"), class = "factor"), PERSON_IDENTIFIER_VALUE = c(9021099834,9021099834, 8021088834)), .Names = c("idnty_frst_nm", "idnty_last_nm","PERSON_IDENTIFIER_VALUE"), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame") 

sample_data$name<-paste(sample_data$idnty_frst_nm, sample_data$idnty_last_nm)

innov.df<-sample_data 
rownames(innov.df)<-1:nrow(innov.df)

#Checking for duplicate names, using 'agrep' function and storing intermediate results in table 'p'

p<-data.frame(a=integer(),b=integer())

k<-1    
#for(i in 1:nrow(innov.df)){
foreach(i = 1:nrow(innov.df)) %:% #this is a nesting operator

  foreach (j = 1:nrow(innov.df)) %dopar% {    
  #for(j in 1:nrow(innov.df)){

  agrep(innov.df$name[i], innov.df$name[j],                     
                  ignore.case=TRUE, value=FALSE,                    
                  max.distance = 0.07, useBytes = TRUE)

    if(i!=j)         
    {      
      if((innov.df[i,2]==innov.df[j,2])&&(innov.df[i,3]==innov.df[j,3]))        
      {         
        p[k,1]<-min(i,j)         
        p[k,2]<-max(i,j)      
        k<-k+1        
      }
    }
  } 
p
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong? The expected output is:

```
a   b
```

1   1   2

which shows that there is a duplicate of the first item..

Comment: Your example is not really reproducible, but `foreach` loops use multi-process parallelization, which means each process does *not* share memory with the main process. Thus, the `p` and `k` values that you modify inside them are completely independent of the ones you defined outside (they're copies).

Comment: Also, even if the processes did share memory, you would have a race condition because you're updating `k` without any synchronization. You won't be able to directly replace `for` loops with `foreach` and profit.

Comment: Can you show us an example of what your desired output is?

Comment: Sorry, I just  made it reproducible..

Comment: It's still not quite reproducible (you call `innov.df$name` but you don't have that field for example). It might be more helpful if you show us an example on its own of your regular for loop that does work, and then we can help translate it to the foreach version.

Comment: Hi Esther, Actually it is defined line 10 and then I assign sample_data to innov.d.. Now it should be replicable.. Thank you for looking at it!!